# Simulate 308 redirect in nginx 1.12

Tags: nginx, redirect

Redirect with status code 308 (Permanent Redirect) is supported in nginx [only since version 1.13](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/877).

How can one simulate a 308 redirect using only the facilities offered by nginx 1.12?

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for nginx 1.14, which will be out in a couple of months.

You can use nginx 1.13, which is available already.

If you don't want to do either, you'll need to provide a 308 outside nginx somehow. For instance, in a trivial PHP script.

```
location = /oldurl {
    rewrite ^ /308.php?location=$new_uri break;
}
```

Where 308.php might look like:

```php
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect");
header("Status: 308 Permanent Redirect");
header("Location: {$_GET['location']}");
```